# How to divide 2 integer numbers and get the output stored in float variable using ksh shell scripting?

Tags: shell, ksh

I have below values stored in the respective variables:

```
s=$(nice grep -i "sf WOW" *`date --date='1 hour ago' +%y%m%d%H`* | grep -i "TRAF:5" | wc -l)
f=$(nice grep -i "sf WOW" *`date --date='1 hour ago' +%y%m%d%H`* | grep -i "TRAF:7" | wc -l)
a=`expr $s + $f`
```

I need to store the division output in a float variable with an accuracy of 5 digits.

Comment: Please post your code as text instead of image.

Comment: Try `bc <<< "scale=5; $s + $f"`'

Comment: s=$(nice grep -i "sf WOW" *`date --date='1 hour ago' +%y%m%d%H`* | grep -i "TRAF:5" | wc -l)

f=$(nice grep -i "sf WOW" *`date --date='1 hour ago' +%y%m%d%H`* | grep -i "TRAF:7" | wc -l)

a=`expr $s + $f`

Comment: The code is getting modified with some formatting syntax of this website.

Comment: That's because you are using `ksh` but tagged as `bash` !

Comment: `ksh` is not `bash`. They are different. `ksh` doesn't accept heredocs introduced with `<<<` because that is a *"bash-ism"*.

Comment: I can store value using this command. x=$(bc -l <<< '10/13')

But I want to use variables in that command instead of values.

Comment: To check your shell, try `echo $0` as the next line in your script. Then `ps -p "$$"`

Comment: If you want variables expanded, you must use double quotes, not single quotes.

Comment: I am using ksh. echo $SHELL
/bin/ksh
So could you please give a command which supports in ksh?

Comment: a=$(echo "x/y" | bc)
Runtime error (func=(main), adr=5): Divide by zero

Comment: Try `answer=$(echo "scale=5; $s + $f" | bc)`

Comment: It didn't work. a=$(echo "scale=5; $s/$f" | bc)
(standard_in) 1: syntax error

Comment: Try `echo "scale=5; $s + $f"`

Comment: Then try `s=1.11111; f=2.22222` and run the previous `echo` again.

Comment: echo "scale=5; $x + $y"
scale=5; 52 + 58

But in my case, both x and y are integer variables. I need to do x/y and store z as a float value.

Comment: I don't why is this behaving like below. No clue.

echo "scale=5; $x + $y"
scale=5; 52 + 58
hi=`echo "scale=2;2/3" |bc`
echo $hi
.66
hi=`echo "scale=2;x/y" |bc`
Runtime error (func=(main), adr=11): Divide by zero
echo $x
52
echo $y
58

Comment: Then use `echo "scale=5; $x / $y" | bc`

Comment: Hey Mark, Thank you so much! It worked for me.
z=$(echo "scale=2; $x * 100 / $y" | bc)
echo $z
89.65
Thanks a ton!! Really appreciate it!

Comment: How do I mark your comment as the solution? If you can write it as a separate reply I would definitely mark that as the solution to this question. Thank you!

Comment: I can't do that as the question is closed for being a duplicate. But don't worry, be happy! Good luck with your project.

Comment: @SachinAravind : I guess you have ksh93, because earlier ksh version don't have floating point numbers. But then, you should be able to do simply `a=s+f`, provided that you declared the variables expicitly as _float_.

Answer (score 1):

```
echo "scale=5; 355/113" | bc
3.14159
```

Comment: Hi bro, it didn't work.

Comment: echo "scale=5; x/a" | bc -l

Runtime error (func=(main), adr=11): Divide by zero

echo $a

110

echo $x

52

Comment: @SachinAravind `$a` is the bash variable. If you replace xoids example `355/113` with `x/a`, you need to assign the `bc` variables `a` and `x` first: `echo "scale=5; x=$x; a=$a; x/a" | bc -l` - or simply: `echo "scale=5; $x/$a" | bc -l`